# Pitfalls post about `NumberForm`, `MatrixForm`, etc

Tags: discussion

I was looking for a duplicate post for [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190941/need-help-with-order-of-evaluations) today, and I figured there *must* be an answer in the [Pitfalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) post about the issues that come up with using functions like `NumberForm` and `MatrixForm` that are purely for formatting purposes. Are my eyes and brain not working correctly, or is there not one there?  If not, then that seems like a topic for an answer under the **General Guidelines** or **Syntax and Semantics** headings. Does anyone feel like checking there to see if my brain has deceived me, and if not, does anyone feel like adding that post?

Comment: Would point no. 8 in [the “basic syntax issues” answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951) in the Pitfalls question work as a canonical answer? I think it’s pretty detailed.

Comment: @MarcoB. Yeah, see? That's my brain not being able to read today. That works fine. Thanks.

Comment: There is also [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations) which appears to directly adress that issue alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of having this answered:

- point no. 8 of the [Basic Syntax Issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951) answer to the Pitfalls question touches upon the topic;
- [Why does MatrixForm affect calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations) directly addresses the issue.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks!  My brain was broken that day, apparently.